# return to default content after using load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I using load() to load content from other page to target element like this:

```
<div id="container">
 <h1>Example Heading</h1>
 <p>Example content.</p>
 <a href="#" role="button" id="load">Load more</a>
</div>
<a href="#" role="button" id="back">Back to default</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#load').click(function() {
          $('#container').load('content.html');
    };
});
```

Result

> New Content
>   Back to default

So the question is: How to I get back to default content with button Back without refresh the whole page?

Comment: Save the content in a variable on page load and put it back when the back button is clicked?

Comment: Can you help me with that? I think catch the button clicked event will refresh the whole page, doesn't it?

Comment: Do you mean the browser's back button or the _Back to default_ button you have up there?

Comment: The _Back to default_ button, thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's no way for the "back" anchor button to refresh the page without any code, so no it won't.

For your problem, you can [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element after the page gets loaded, (`clone()` basically copies the element contents) and then when you click on *load more*, it's going to load the html contents and when *back to default* is clicked, it's going to put the elements we have cloned back to the container. Here's how you do it:

On:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Clone the container's elements:

```
cloned = $('#container').clone();
```

When the back button is clicked, put it back into the container:

```
$('#back').click(function() {
      $('#container').html(cloned);
});
```

One last thing is the *load more* button won't be triggered again because it has been dynamically put back after being replaced by some html. So the `click` handler is not attached to it, so change your *load more* click event to:

```
$(document).on('click','#load',function() {
      $('#container').load('content.html');
});
```

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) attaches event handler to dynamically created elements.

Here's a demo:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y99Dm/)**